# react-router in a CEP extension (e.g. Premiere Pro)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, adobe, complex-event-processing

i am trying to use a react-router in a CEP extension. my routing looks like this:

```
let prefix = decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname).replace("index.html", "")

  <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={prefix + "index.html"} component={MainComponent} />
        <Route path={prefix + "other/:otherId"} component={OtherComponent} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
```

This seems to be the only way to trick the router to accept the location of an extension - since it has a document.location of 'file://path/to/cep/extention/index.html'.
The problem i am facing now, is that this only works on Mac - but consistently fails to match any path on windows. I suspect this is because the location on windows looks like: 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Common%20Files/…be/CEP/extensions/extension-name/index.html' and the 'C:' confuses the router?

is there any way to trick the router to accept this kind of location URI?

Comment: so i was able to work around the Route never matching the MainComponent path by just dropping the "path" element completely. The remaining issue is - how do i get the relative path "otherComponent" to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution - use a HashRouter instead of a BrowserRouter. This also allows the use of normal paths:

```
import { Route, HashRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
<Router >
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={MainComponent} />
    <Route path="/other/:otherId" component={OtherComponent} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Redux, this could be solved by using 'createHashHistory'. In the same way as the accepted answer, this allows you to use normal paths.
Here's what it might look like to configure your redux store.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

const history = createHashHistory();
const routeMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const middlewares = [routeMiddleware];

const configureStore = (initialState) => {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer(history),
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
    );
}

const store = configureStore({});

export default store;
```